# How can I include nanohttpd to my gradle project?

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

The gradle files below are from new java android project with Empty Activity only. 
"//added" denotes what I have tried to do
The files only contain the modified lines to reduce code to text ratio to make stackoverflow happy.

Example build.gradle(my project has 2): 
1

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"
        classpath "org.nanohttpd:nanohttpd:2.2.0"//added
    }
}
```

2

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.nanohttpd:nanohttpd:2.2.0'//added
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Why do you put the nanohttpd in your buildscript dependencies  ? 
In your dependencies should be enough.

And what error do you have with this build

Comment: Remove the added line in your top `build.gradle` file. The `dependencies` in the `buildscript` are for Gradle plugins, not libraries that your app code depends upon.

Comment: I am dumb asf, I kept on thinking that grayed out libraries are the ones that haven't been found aren't included.